# Add image to collapsable content header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm following the collapsible content doc at - 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

Is there a method of adding an image to the right, within the header field (in code below the header field is referenced by 'Test').

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>Test</h3><add image here>
    </div>
```

I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xMbyP/3/
- Example #2: http://jsfiddle.net/xMbyP/4/
- Navbar idea: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y3qT/12/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>I'm a header</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>With Image <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/images/us.png" alt="US Flag" /></h3><p>I'm another collapsible content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, http://jsfiddle.net/xMbyP/4/ pushes the image to the right down sligtly and causes the header height to be increased slightly. The code style="float:right;" seems to be causing this, is there another method of alighing the image to the right ?

Comment: This does the trick -       <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>With Image to the right<img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/images/us.png" alt="US Flag" style="float:right; margin-top:-15px;" /></h3><p>I'm another collapsible content.</p>
        </div>

Comment: How safe is it setting the margin val to a minus figure ?

Comment: each browser is going to render it differently. I use Chrome on Linux and what I did looked great. I also tested the -15px which cuts off half of the image. Also when device testing it might look different as well for each device.

Comment: Also on the jsfiddle page you can resize the boxes by dragging the bar dividers to get a feel on how it might look on a mobile screen

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xMbyP/4/ displays fine on a blackberry running webkit browser, not too concerned with firefox. Thanks again.

Comment: Great solution and if you want the heading to align then you set img style="vertical-align: middle"

Answer (score 0):

What about using two divs with left and right float inside main div?

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <div style="float: left;"><h3>Test</h3><add image here></div>
    <div style="float: right;"><img src="parth/to/image.ext" /></div>
</div>
```