# How to add multiple icons in jquery mobile collapsible list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, icons

I would like to add an another icon near by the plus icon of the jquery mobile collapsible list. But could not able to add it since jquery mobile creates that icon dynamically. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Another option would be to add an image to the header as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144503/add-image-to-collapsable-content-header).

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly a hack but you can wait for the page to initialize, then find the list-view widget and append the jQuery Mobile HTML for an icon to each list-item:

```
//wait for a certain pseudo-page to initialize
$(document).delegate('#home', 'pageinit', function () {

    //find the listview and append to it's second tier children (the `<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" />` element)
    $(this).find('ul[data-role="listview"]').children().children().append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow" style="right:30px;">&nbsp;</span>');
});​
```

Notice I changed the `right` CSS property of the new icon so it doesn't overlap the initial icon.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uZxXB/

Comment: Thanks a lot jasper! Its been a while I started implementing. This works great in List but when comes to Collapsible list, i implemented in my own way but the problem I am getting is when you click in the collapsible header both the icons changes to minus sign. see this code http://jsfiddle.net/uZxXB/

Comment: sorry i sent the wrong link, here you go [link](http://jsfiddle.net/chillbird/uZxXB/145/)

Comment: @Chillbird If you make one of the icons not a plus/minus icon then it won't change on click: http://jsfiddle.net/uZxXB/146/. If you really need one of those icons then create custom versions of them by copying the CSS for the originals and then adding a suffix or prefix to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="left" >
                        <h1 ><span    class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow ui-btn-icon-right" style="right:30px;">&nbsp;</span>Header</h1>
```

You can add it in html

Two icons one in the left and other for the right and change css of jQuery min to text align center

```
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn{text-align:center;margin:0;border-left-width:0;
```